# Download a file from Google Drive By Url In Android

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am developing an app to uploading ,displaying and downloading files from G Drive. Unfortunately When downloading I am getting
 **com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 401 Unauthorized.**

Please help me to solve this problem.

Here I am assigning

```
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this,DriveScopes.DRIVE);

service=new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),new GsonFactory(),credential).build();
```

My Code Is:

```
package com.example.googledrive;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.google.api.client.extensions.android.http.AndroidHttp;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException;
import com.google.api.client.http.FileContent;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.client.json.gson.GsonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Children;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.Get;
import com.google.api.services.drive.DriveScopes;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ChildList;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.ChildReference;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.FileList;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1;
    static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 2;
    static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 3;

    private static Uri fileUri;
    private static Drive service;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private GoogleAccountCredential credential;

    String fileId;
    String fileName;
    String downloadUrl;
    ListView listView;
    Activity activity;
    String sdCardPadth;
    List<File> allFileList;
    ArrayList<String> fileType;
    ArrayList<String> mainTitleList;
    ArrayList<String> fileIdList;
    ArrayList<String> alternateUrlList;
    ArrayList<Integer> fileSizeList;
    FileTitlesAdapter myAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.uploadedFilesList);
        allFileList = new ArrayList<File>();
        mainTitleList = new ArrayList<String>();
        alternateUrlList = new ArrayList<String>();
        fileSizeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        fileType = new ArrayList<String>();
        fileIdList=new ArrayList<String>();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait....");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        activity = this;

        credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this,DriveScopes.DRIVE);
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(),REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, final int arg2,long arg3) {
                // String str=itemArray.get(arg2).toString().trim();
                System.out.println("mainTitleList size==="+mainTitleList.size());
                System.out.println("arg2==="+arg2);
                fileName = (String)mainTitleList.get(arg2);             
                mainTitleList.clear();              
                //fileSizeList.clear();
                final String fileTypeStr=fileType.get(arg2);
                fileType.clear();
                if(fileTypeStr.contains("application/vnd.google-apps.folder"))
                {
                    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                    boolean b=true;
                    try {                       
                        String dirUrl=alternateUrlList.get(arg2);                       
                        alternateUrlList.clear();
                        System.out.println("Folder Name Is:"+fileName);
                        System.out.println("Folder Type Is:"+fileTypeStr);
                        System.out.println("Folder URL Is:"+dirUrl);
                        String fileId=fileIdList.get(arg2);
                        System.out.println("Folder Id Is:"+fileId);                     
                        //retrieveAllFilesFromDir(service, fileId, b);                      
                        //retrieveAllFiles1(service, b, fileId);
                        //Files.List request = service.children().get(fileId, null);
                        Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("'" + fileId + "' in parents ");
                        retrieveAllFiles(service,request,b);                        
                        //retrieveAllFiles(service, b);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        System.out.println("Exception In retrieveAllFiles Dir Is:"+e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                        }
                        });t.start();       
                }
                else
                {       

                try {
                    System.out.println("fileSizeList size===="+fileSizeList.size());
                    System.out.println("arg2===="+arg2);                    
                    Integer fileSize = (int) fileSizeList.get(arg2);
                    downloadUrl = alternateUrlList.get(arg2);
                    byte[] size = new byte[fileSize];
                    int byteRead = 0, byteWritten = 0;
                    sdCardPadth = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();


                    System.out.println("Download Url==="+downloadUrl);

                    new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            InputStream inStream=downloadFile(service, downloadUrl);

                            java.io.File inFile=new java.io.File(sdCardPadth+"/"+fileName+"1");
                            System.out.println("File Succesfully Stored");

                        }
                    }).start();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("Exception In get Integer Is:" + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
            final int resultCode, final Intent data) {      
        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:            
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null
                    && data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName = data
                        .getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    service = getDriveService(credential);      
                    final boolean b=false;                  
                    Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable() {                        
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try
                            {
                                Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("hidden="+b);
                                    retrieveAllFiles(service,request,b);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                System.out.println("Exception Is:"+e);
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }) ;t.start();

                }
            }
            break;
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                System.out.println("REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION case Is:"
                        + REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                saveFileToDrive();
            } else {
                startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(),
                        REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
            }
            break;
        case CAPTURE_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                System.out.println("CAPTURE_IMAGE case Is:" + CAPTURE_IMAGE);
                saveFileToDrive();
            }
        }
    }
    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // File's binary content
                    System.out.println("run method");
                    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
                    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg",fileContent);
                    // File's metadata.
                    File body = new File();
                    body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
                    body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
                    File file=null;
                    try {

                        file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.println("Exception In Insert File Is"+e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (file != null) {
                        showToast("Photo uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
                        System.out.println("photo sucessfullly uploaded:"+ fileId);boolean b=false;
Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("hidden="+b);
                        retrieveAllFiles(service,request,b);                        
                    }
                } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
                    startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t.start();
    }
    private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                new GsonFactory(), credential).build();
    }

    public void showToast(final String toast) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service,Files.List request,boolean b) throws IOException {
        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        final ArrayList<String> titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
        String fileUrl = "";
        do {
            try {
                FileList files = request.execute();
                result.addAll(files.getItems());
                request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                    File tempFile = result.get(i);
                    String fileTypeStr = tempFile.getMimeType();                
                    String fileName = tempFile.getTitle();
                    titleList.add(fileName);    
                    fileId = tempFile.getId();
                    fileIdList.add(fileId);                 
                    fileUrl = tempFile.getAlternateLink();
                    System.out.println("<><>< fileUrl Is:" + fileUrl);
                    alternateUrlList.add(fileUrl);

                    fileType.add(fileTypeStr);
                    mainTitleList.add(fileName);                    

                    try {
                        Integer fileSize =tempFile.getFileSize()==null?100:(int) (long) tempFile.getFileSize();
                        fileSizeList.add(fileSize);
                        System.out.println("<><>< fileSize Is:" + fileSize);
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        fileSizeList.add(2000);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }



                try {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            myAdapter = new FileTitlesAdapter(activity,
                                    fileType, mainTitleList, alternateUrlList,
                                    fileSizeList);
                            listView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {


                    System.out.println("Exception Setting ListView Is:" + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("An error occurred in retrieveAllFiles:"+ e);
                request.setPageToken(null);
            }
        } while (request.getPageToken() != null
                && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);
        return result;
    }


     private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, String url) {
         System.out.println("downloadFile is called service=="+service);
            if (url != null && url.length() > 0) {
              try {
                  System.out.println("downloadFile is called try");
                HttpResponse resp =service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(url)).execute();
                System.out.println("resp.getContent()===="+resp.getContent());
                return resp.getContent();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception Is:"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
              }
            } else {
                 System.out.println("No Exception No Output");
              return null;
            }
          }


}
```

Comment: Could you print the error message? You can find out more about how to catch error from this [page](https://developers.google.com/drive/handle-errors#catching_exceptions_with_client_libraries).The credentials might have expired or the user might have revoked access to your app.

Comment: Kindly post your code and Logcat

Comment: Error Message Is:<TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>

</HEAD>

 <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
 <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
<H2>Error 401</H2>
 
</BODY>

 </HTML>

at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1047)

at com.example.googledrive.MainActivity.downloadFile(MainActivity.java:495)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is code that I use to download File from google Drive

```
   new AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            File file = service.files().get("path in drive").execute();
            java.io.File toFile = new java.io.File("where you want to store");
            toFile.createNewFile();
            HttpDownloadManager downloader = new HttpDownloadManager(file, toFile);
            downloader.setListener(new HttpDownloadManager.FileDownloadProgressListener() {

                public void downloadProgress(long bytesRead, long totalBytes) {
                    Log.i("chauster",totalBytes);
                    Log.i("chauster",bytesRead);
                }

                @Override
                public void downloadFinished() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void downloadFailedWithError(Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
                }                       
            });
            return downloader.download(service);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return false;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        };
    }.execute();
```

HttpDownloadManager.java

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;
import com.grandex.ShareInfomation.ShareData;
import com.grandex.ShareInfomation.ShareData.ToolTapState;

public class HttpDownloadManager {
    private String donwloadUrl;
    private String toFile;
    private FileDownloadProgressListener listener;
    private long totalBytes;

    public void setListener(FileDownloadProgressListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    } 

    public HttpDownloadManager(File sourceFile, java.io.File destinationFile) {
        super(); 
        this.donwloadUrl = sourceFile.getDownloadUrl();
        this.toFile = destinationFile.toString();
        this.totalBytes = sourceFile.getFileSize();
    } 

    public static interface FileDownloadProgressListener {
        public void downloadProgress(long bytesRead, long totalBytes);

        public void downloadFinished();

        public void downloadFailedWithError(Exception e);
    }

    public boolean download(Drive service) {
        HttpResponse respEntity = null;
        try {
            // URL url = new URL(urlString);
            respEntity = service.getRequestFactory()
                    .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(donwloadUrl)).execute();
            InputStream in = respEntity.getContent();
            if(totalBytes == 0) {
                totalBytes = respEntity.getContentLoggingLimit();
            } 
            try { 
                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(toFile) {

                    @Override
                    public void write(byte[] buffer, int byteOffset,
                            int byteCount) throws IOException {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.write(buffer, byteOffset, byteCount);
                        }
                    }
                };
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len1 = 0;
                long bytesRead = 0;
                while ((len1 = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    f.write(buffer, 0, len1);
                    if (listener != null) {
                        bytesRead += len1;
                        listener.downloadProgress(bytesRead, totalBytes);
                    }
                }
                f.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (listener != null) {
                    listener.downloadFailedWithError(e);
                }
                return false;
            }
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.downloadFinished();
            }
            return true;

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            if (listener != null) {
                listener.downloadFailedWithError(ex);
                return false;
            }
        } finally {
            if(respEntity != null) {
                try {
                    respEntity.disconnect();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. Please tell me what is "path in drive". Are you meaning url of that file?

Comment: oh... In google Drive that is id (googledrive file.getId(); )

Comment: Hi , i am using google play service for accesing google drive. I have faced similar problem. Could you help me?? @VivekRavi

Comment: What's your problem @DarkenShooter

Comment: I am using google play service for accesing google drive. I have got the file URL . but i cant download the file as we normally can download using any url. Many said that a file cant be downloaded by using google play service for accesing google drive.  i hv got a similar thread which is not solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431299/downloading-file-from-google-drive-using-filemetadata-getwebcontentlink    @VivekRavi

Comment: It would be very helpful if you give me the full sample which you had solved. I had stacked in this problem for more than 1 months but  cant get any solution yet. @VivekRavi

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your code are you setting the Authorization header.

You need something like

```
setRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth " + "***ACCESS_TOKEN***");
```

For any 401/403 errors it's well worth getting your request working on the Oauth. Try this out

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. But can u tell me where to put this above line.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code for download apk file from google drive

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Add uses permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
```

Create a file provider

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path
    name="external"
    path="." />
<external-files-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
<files-path
    name="files"
    path="." />
```

Now declare the file provider inside the manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths" />
```

Add some value inside strings.xml file

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Download APK</string>
<string name="downloading">Downloading...</string>
<string name="title_file_download">APK is downloading</string>
<string name="storage_access_required">Storage access is required to downloading the file.</string>
<string name="storage_permission_denied">Storage permission request was denied.</string>
<string name="ok">OK</string>
```

Create a download controller

```
package com.hktpayment.mytmoney.pos.mauritius.util
import android.app.Dialog
import android.app.DownloadManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.database.Cursor
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Environment
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import com.hktpayment.mytmoney.pos.mauritius.BuildConfig
import com.hktpayment.mytmoney.pos.mauritius.R
import java.io.File




class DownloadController(
private val context: Context,
private val url: String,
private val progressBar: Dialog
) {
companion object {
    private const val FILE_NAME = "SampleDownloadApp.apk"
    private const val FILE_BASE_PATH = "file://"
    private const val MIME_TYPE = "application/vnd.android.package-archive"
    private const val PROVIDER_PATH = ".provider"
    private const val APP_INSTALL_PATH = "application/vnd.android.package- 
    archive"
    }


    private lateinit var downloadManager: DownloadManager

    fun enqueueDownload() {
    var destination =
        
    context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() 
    + "/"
    destination += FILE_NAME
    val uri = Uri.parse("$FILE_BASE_PATH$destination")
    val file = File(destination)
    if (file.exists()) file.delete()
    downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as 
    DownloadManager
    val downloadUri = Uri.parse(url)
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri)
    request.setMimeType(MIME_TYPE)
    request.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.title_file_download))
    request.setDescription(context.getString(R.string.downloading))
    // set destination
    request.setDestinationUri(uri)
    showInstallOption(destination, uri)
    // Enqueue a new download and same the referenceId
    downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    Toast.makeText(context, context.getString(R.string.downloading), 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        .show()
     }


    private fun showInstallOption(
    destination: String,
    uri: Uri
) {
    // set BroadcastReceiver to install app when .apk is downloaded
    progressBar.show()
    val onComplete = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(
            context: Context,
            intent: Intent
        ) {
            progressBar.dismiss()
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    context,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + PROVIDER_PATH,
                    File(destination)
                )
                val install = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                install.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true)
                install.data = contentUri
                context.startActivity(install)
                context.unregisterReceiver(this)
                // finish()
            } else {
                val install = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                install.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                install.setDataAndType(
                    uri,
                    APP_INSTALL_PATH
                )
                context.startActivity(install)
                context.unregisterReceiver(this)
                // finish()
            }
        }
    }
    context.registerReceiver(onComplete, IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE))
}
```

}

In this activity, we are checking storage permission first. If permission is granted than calling download function otherwise requesting for storage permission.

```
 val apkUrl = "https://download .apk"
    downloadController = DownloadController(this, apkUrl)

 downloadController.enqueueDownload()
```