# Cannot create spreadsheet in google drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-drive-android-api

I tried to create a spreadsheet in Android. It sent a success message but it wasn't created.

I used the following code to create it:

```
MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
.setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet").setTitle("MonthExpense").build();
IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
.newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
.setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
.setInitialDriveContents(result.getDriveContents())
.build(appobject.mGoogleApiClient);
try {
activity.startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, 56, null, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

If I use any other mimetype it works correctly can anyone please guide me in the right way.

**Edit** 
If i try any other mime type it works with out problem,  So i guess the problem related with "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"

Comment: Probably the problem is that you are trying to upload Google spreadsheet without any body or maybe you should have it working by using the pure Java Drive SDK.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to add body in it.

Comment: I have try with java sdk too but it returns 400 error

Comment: See the reference on these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569851/how-do-i-upload-file-to-google-drive-from-android, 
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/create-file

Comment: refer this link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49297056/1201441, there describe upload file in google drive. you can upload any type of file just change file_path and respected Mime type

Answer (score 0):

Try to change application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet to application/vnd.ms-excel

Create a WorkBook. This is the end of my working code

```
final private ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(final DriveContentsResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
            return;
        }
        final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

        // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

 //CREATE YOUR WORKBOOK HERE
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    try {
                        wb.write(bos);
                        byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
                        outputStream.write(bytes);
                        //WORKBOOK FILENAME
                        writer.write(fileName);
                        wb.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }

                    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setTitle(fileName)
                            .setMimeType("application/vnd.ms-excel")
                            .setStarred(true).build();

                    // create a file on root folder
                    Drive.DriveApi
                            .getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                            .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet,
                                    driveContents)
                            .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
```

Comment: After creating as MS-excel.  is it possible to use via spread sheet api ?

Comment: I don't see why not. I took a quick look at the Google Sheets api and I didn't see anything in there to stop it. Just fyi, I am able to open this file on Google Sheets with ease.

Comment: ok thanks for the information, I will try to implement that and get back you soon.