# How I can create and upload google spreadsheet using android app?

Tags: android, spreadsheet, google-drive-android-api

I have spent too much time on this so I would like to ask about it. I want to create and upload google spreadsheet using android. I know that I should use **Drive API** to do this. I know how to create file using this API(even excel file) but when **setMimeType** is set to **application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet** I receive an error on the device: **Error while trying to create the file.**

```
    @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    // create new contents resource
    Drive.DriveApi.newDriveContents(getGoogleApiClient())
            .setResultCallback(driveContentsCallback);
}

final private ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult> driveContentsCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveContentsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveContentsResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    showMessage("Error while trying to create new file contents");
                    return;
                }
                final DriveContents driveContents = result.getDriveContents();

                // Perform I/O off the UI thread.
                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // write content to DriveContents
                        OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
                        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream);
                        try {
                            writer.write("Hello World!");
                            writer.write("Hello World!");
                            writer.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        }

                        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                .setTitle("Orders")
                                .setMimeType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet")
                                .setStarred(true).build();



                        // create a file on root folder
                        Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
                                .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, driveContents)
                                .setResultCallback(fileCallback);
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        };

final private ResultCallback<DriveFileResult> fileCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveFileResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DriveFileResult result) {
                if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                    showMessage("Error while trying to create the file");
                    return;
                }
                showMessage("Created a file with content: " + result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
                storeId(result.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
                kill_activity();
            }
        };v
```

Comment: missclick, not sure if it is possible to remove it

Comment: done, I don't post here too much, sorry for that

Comment: JUST A WILD GUESS. Your content is a plain text. Shouldn't the spreadsheet (with a mime that is correct in you code) content be some predefined binary structure?  It is the same as if you tried to write "hello world" into a "image/jpeg" mime, I guess it would fail as well (test it by switching the mime to "text/plain" first).

Comment: it works fine with text/plain and application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: Apparently, the 'application/vnd.ms-excel' mime can accept the plain text, but  'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'  can't. I would just try to figure out how the GooSheet content should look like. Can't help more, never done anything in the area of GooSheets. Try to find / add more SO tags for GooSheets.

Answer (score 2):

The GDAA does not currently support creation Google Docs files. You will have to use the [Google Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/android) in your Android application to do this.

Answer (score 2):

@user3212019, You can upload a excel spread sheet in google drive from your android app, just follow as below.

> I think you aware of [Quick Start](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/drive-android-quickstart) on Google Android site.
>
> Now create a excel sheet by using [jxl jar library](https://www.mkyong.com/java/jexcel-api-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/)

Now follow the [Start Integrating Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) and Integrate Google SignIn with Drive scope (Drive.SCOPE_FILE) in your app.

Now final and last copy paste below activity code in your activity and then give a excel sheet path in saveFileToDrive(file_path) method.

```
public class UploadFileInGoogleDriveActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = "tejadroid-quickstart";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN = 0;

    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private DriveClient mDriveClient;
    private DriveResourceClient mDriveResourceClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        signIn();
    }

    /**
     * Start sign in activity.
     */
    private void signIn() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Start sign in");
        mGoogleSignInClient = buildGoogleSignInClient();
        startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN);

    }

    /**
     * Build a Google SignIn client.
     */
    private GoogleSignInClient buildGoogleSignInClient() {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions =
                new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                        .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                        .build();
        return GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, signInOptions);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_SIGN_IN:
                Log.i(TAG, "Sign in request code");
                // Called after user is signed in.
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Signed in successfully.");
                    // Use the last signed in account here since it already have a Drive scope.
                    mDriveClient = Drive.getDriveClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));
                    // Build a drive resource client.
                    mDriveResourceClient =
                            Drive.getDriveResourceClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this));

                    // Excel Sheet path from SD card
                    final String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/Expense Manager/ExpenseReport/ExpenseDiary.xls";
                    saveFileToDrive(filePath);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a new file and save it to Drive.
     */
    private void saveFileToDrive(final String filePath) {
        // Start by creating a new contents, and setting a callback.
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");

        mDriveResourceClient
                .createContents()
                .continueWithTask(
                        new Continuation<DriveContents, Task<Void>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Task<Void> then(@NonNull Task<DriveContents> task) throws Exception {
                                return createFileIntentSender(task.getResult(), new File(filePath));
                            }
                        })
                .addOnFailureListener(
                        new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to create new contents.", e);
                            }
                        });
    }

    /**
     * Creates an {@link IntentSender} to start a dialog activity with configured {@link
     * CreateFileActivityOptions} for user to create a new photo in Drive.
     */
    private Task<Void> createFileIntentSender(DriveContents driveContents, File file) throws Exception {
        Log.i(TAG, "New contents created.");

        OutputStream outputStream = driveContents.getOutputStream();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        try {
            try {
                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
            } finally {
                outputStream.close();
            }
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }


        // Create the initial metadata - MIME type and title.
        // Note that the user will be able to change the title later.
        MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet =
                new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                        .setMimeType("application/vnd.ms-excel")
                        .setTitle("ExcelSheet.xls")
                        .build();
        // Set up options to configure and display the create file activity.
        CreateFileActivityOptions createFileActivityOptions =
                new CreateFileActivityOptions.Builder()
                        .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                        .setInitialDriveContents(driveContents)
                        .build();

        return mDriveClient
                .newCreateFileActivityIntentSender(createFileActivityOptions)
                .continueWith(
                        new Continuation<IntentSender, Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public Void then(@NonNull Task<IntentSender> task) throws Exception {
                                startIntentSenderForResult(task.getResult(), REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
                                return null;
                            }
                        });
    }


}
```

Just debug app and look in to Google Drive there your file exist in root folder of drive.

Comment: I know that's how android-samples does it, too, but... how about an example that doesn't stream data on the UI thread?

Comment: @kaay, I can't understand what you means, but yes, about an example, thats all maintain by thread of drive library. you can set progress dialog in while start and stop once upload success from drive.

Comment: I mean that createFileIntentSender does a lot of work before returning its Task. And it's run inside continueWithTask(Task) rather than continueWithTask(Executor, Task), so all that work is done on the main Thread. Try replacing all the Stream stuff with a simple Thread.sleep(60000) and you'll see an ANR.  BTW. sorry for being a bit rude.