# Which libs do I need to use for DriveClient?

Tags: java, android, google-sheets, import

I'm trying to use the Google Sheets API on Android. I found an appropriate class here using this question ([How I can create and upload google spreadsheet using android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067691/how-i-can-create-and-upload-google-spreadsheet-using-android-app)).

The class "public class UploadFileInGoogleDriveActivity extends Activity"

But I'm unfamiliar with DriveClient and DriveResourceClient.
I have the imports:

```
"import java.io.OutputStream;"
"import java.io.InputStream;"
"import java.io.File;"
"import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;"
"import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;"
"import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;"
"import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;"
"import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;"
"import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;"
"import android.os.Bundle;"
"import android.util.Log;"
"import android.content.IntentSender;"
"import android.content.Intent;"
"import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;"
"import androidx.annotation.Nullable;"
```

What other libraries can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Add these to your gradle

```
  implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:11.6.0'
```

and imports will be

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Scope;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveId;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveResourceClient;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.OpenFileActivityOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.Filters;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.query.SearchableField;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource;
```