# How to get the direct download link of a file by google drive api v3 in java

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

### How to get the direct download link of a file by google drive api v3 in java ?

Hi all,
I've worked with Google Drive Api in Android for a week, I used both Android Drive SDK and Drive Rest Api for java but I can't find the way how to how to get the direct download link of a file (anyone can read) on Drive.
I've try [How to get the url of a file of google drive to download in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30421889/how-to-get-the-url-of-a-file-of-google-drive-to-download-in-android) but it's not work.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that you have the actual **FILE-ID** for the file , you can download it using the download link

**drive.google.com/uc?id=*FILE-ID*&export=download**

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, thanks Michael, you saved me hours of hair pulling!

Comment: january 2020 this is not working anymore... says 404 :(

Comment: November 2020 works fine for a public file. (atleast for media files)

Comment: May 2021 after running automated scripts to download public files 403 error after 1 minute

Comment: @Michael Nyamande this is now not working in im not able to download file programmatically in android.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the direct download link of a file, `DriveFile` doesn't seem to be what you're looking for. What you can do is to use the Drive API web service instead. Note that you're still required to be authenticated for you to use the API.

Check out the [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads) section of the documentation, there are 3 ways for you to download the file.

> - Download a file — [files.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get) with alt=media [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)
> - Download and export a Google Doc — [files.export](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export)
> - Link a user to a file — webContentLink from the [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)

Another alternative is for you to use the `webContentLink` for you to download the file. However, this is only available for files with binary content in Drive.

Comment: instead of webContentLink use webViewLink. If the file is binary or unable to be loaded directly you will get a Download or Open with screen in the browser.