# Downloading file from google drive using fileMetadata.getWebContentLink()

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am trying to download a file(it could be any file like image,pdf,text etc) using `fileMetadata.getWebContentLink()`

when i print this link it shows something like this:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0Bw6vr2LNxB3iUFJrTk5oZDljaTA&export=download
```

When i put this link into my desktop's browser the file is automatically downloaded. but i cant download this into my app.
I used this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/)  to download using  `new DownloadFileAsync().execute(fileMetadata.getWebContentLink());`

When i make the file public to access in my google drive then it works otherwise it doesn't work.
Can anyone know why is this happening and how to fix this??

Comment: Instead of webcontentlink, use exportlinks

Answer (score 2):

WebcontentLink only works in browsers.

Here's the steps to download a file in your app as it is stated [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/files)

1. Retrieve the Drive File object and open the file contents. (Content is binary)
2. Read the content with Input Stream, save it and close it.